# How to use getRange() method with XWPFDocument and getParagraphText() with XWPFWordExtractor?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting error when i am trying to use getRange with `XWPFDocument` and `getParagraphText()` with `XWPFWordExtractor`. How can i use them together? Do i need to convert my .docx to .doc? If yes then how to do that?

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("textDocx.docx"));
XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
Range range = docx.getRange();
String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Gagravarr i actually got it working, I realised i don't need getRange(). Just use getParagraphs() and getRuns().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **.getRange()** method, just use the **.getParagraphs()** method like this:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilename)) {
        
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);

        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
            // do something with it
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```